# Transitor switch not working at higher voltages

Tags: transistors

I am trying to make a circuit to use a RPi to turn on and off LED board that requires 15V by setting EN_LED high or low. I built it as shown and am currently bench testing it. It works up to about 10V, but at 15V, the EN_LED pin stops working and V_LED always receives the full 15V.

[image: Circuit]

I am new to transistors, so it's likely that I completely messed this up.

Thanks!

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that circuit except *maybe* the pinout of Q1. Some models have collector and emitter reversed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2N2222 for both variants' pinout. Also, R1 is way too small, and is an excessive load on the Pi's IO pin. 10kΩ or more will be fine.

Comment: Probably Simon has your answer, since with the transistor E and C reversed, emitter-base breakdown would occur around 9V, giving Q2 unwanted drive voltage above that.

Comment: You guys were right. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simon was correct. Thank you. I had looked at a generic transistor pin out instead of the specific one and got the pins wrong. I turned Q1 around and it fixed it. Thank you so much for help.